# FME: Set attributes based on a lookup table

Tags: fme-form

I have an XML Reader and I need to write (both inserts and updates) to an SQL database.  The attribute data  in the XML is in a string format, however the values in SQL are stored as IDs.  There is a reference table in SQL that stores a lookup between the field name (ComboType in the screen shot below), string value (Code), and the stored ID (ID).

[image: XML_SQL_Lookup]

So for this example, I need to insert/update 5294 when the "Digger" value is given for the SW_Equipment_Needed tag.  I know that the there is some mapping required between XML and SQL.

What is the best way to retrieve the stored ID value for each of my feature attributes?  There could be any number of attributes per feature depending on what is in the source XML.  There are over 6,000 of these lookup values.  My first instinct is to use Python and the pyodbc module but there could be a cleaner way.

Comment: Have you looked at the Joiner transformer?

Comment: I believe the Joiner transformer will work 1:1.  There are many XML attributes (1 to n) that I need to look up for the internal ID value.

Comment: The Joiner transformer has a cardinality parameter that controls whether it will be a 1:1 match or 1:M. It also has a parameter that decides how to handle 1:M matches (either create a feature for each match, or create an FME 'list' attribute).

Comment: I will take closer look at the Joiner.  I want to join the records based on the XML "Value" to the  SQL"Code" in addition to the XML "attribute" tag to the SQL "ComboType".  I did not see a way to do that as the Joiner only took attribute values and I need to use the field keys.

Comment: It is not pretty, but we got this to work.  Because there are a dynamic number of attributes and lookups, we ended up reading in the SQL table via an SQLExecutor.  The Initiator is exploded and then merged with the result set.  A FeatureMerger puts the data together and finally some list manipulations builds the final attribute/value paris.